# Run commands in new command line terminals (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I would like to run a command that runs three commands in three separate terminals. I've seen a lot of answers for how to achieve this in Linux and OSX but nothing for Windows.

First command (dotnet):

```
x: && cd folder-1\folder-2 && cd MyGame\src\MyGame.Api && dotnet restore --interactive && dotnet run
```

Second command (node):

```
x: && cd folder-1\folder-2 && cd client && npm install && npm run start
```

Third command (git):

```
x: && cd folder-1\folder-2 && git checkout master && git pull
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `start`.

For example,

> start dir

will open a new Command Prompt window and execute `dir` in the new window.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start

Comment: So simple and yet so powerful - thank you very much. Will mark as accepted when I'm allowed to (apparently I have to wait 5 minutes).